# Weird behavior with a BinaryReader

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, stream, binaryreader

I have a socket-based application that exposes received data with a `BinaryReader` object on the client side. I've been trying to debug an issue where the data contained in the reader is not clean... i.e. the buffer that I'm reading contains old data past the size of the new data.

In the code below:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Stream length: {0}", _binaryReader.BaseStream.Length);
byte[] buffer = _binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)_binaryReader.BaseStream.Length);
```

When I comment out the first line, the data doesn't end up being dirty (or, doesn't end up being dirty as regularly) as when I have that print line statement. As far as I can tell, from the server side the data is coming in cleanly, so it's possible that my socket implementation has some issues. But does anyone have any idea why adding that print line would cause the data to be dirty more often?

Comment: the lenght of the byes should be of type long.. where are you declaring it...?

Comment: For example if I wanted to read bytes I would do something like the following FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputfilepath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); just as an example

Comment: I don't know how this applies... As far as I'm aware ReadBytes allocates the buffer and returns it.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. The socket API I'm using gives me a BinaryReader so I'd prefer not to change that. How can I read the bytes received using that? MSDN documentation suggests that what I'm doing is right but it's not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binary reader looks like it is a private member variable (if the leading underscore is a tell tell sign).

Is your application multithreaded? You could be experiencing a race condition if another thread is attempting to do also use your binaryReader while you are reading from it. The fact that you experience issues even without that line seems quite suspect to me.

Comment: It is a member but I have it protected with `AutoResetEvent`s.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your reading logic is correct? `Stream.Length` indicates the length of the *entire* stream, not of the remaining data to be read.

Suppose that, initially, 100 bytes were available. `Length` is 100, and `BinaryReader` corrects reads 100 bytes and advances the stream position by 100. Then, another 20 bytes arrive. `Length` is now 120; however, your `BinaryReader` should only be reading 20 bytes, not 120. The ‘extra’ 100 bytes requested in the second read would either cause it to block or (if the stream is not implemented correctly) break.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was silly and unrelated. I believe my reading logic above is correct, however. The issue was that the _binaryReader I was using was a reference that was not owned by my class and hence the underlying stream was being rewritten with bad data.

Comment: Seems fairly close to the 'if another thread is attempting to also use it while you are writing to it' scenario mentioned above. In any case, good thing you found it!

Comment: Agreed. Marked as the answer.